# Generate RSA keypair in perl efficently with custom PRNG

Tags: perl, rsa, private, public

I would want to generate a public and private keypair, **effciently** (fast) in perl, and be able to input random data for myself.
With inputting random data, I of course mean, that the function requires lets say X random bits to generate a public/private keypair of Y bits, and I should be able to supply these X bits to the function.

So idially, the function should look like:

```
($private, $public) = genRSAkeypair($randomdata, 1024);
```

and $private then contains:

```
----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
....
----END ....
```

and $public contains

```
----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC and so on...
```

$randomdata is then just a string of random bits from any random generator. If $randomdata is consistent between instance1 and instance2, instance1 and instance2 should return the same public and private keys.

If you want to know what the use of this is, is that I plan to make a password-based RSA key generation system, **without any need to store any keys anywhere**. So the key is generated straight out from the password, by using SHA512 chained in a specific way to create static random data.

Of course, the same public and private key must be returned everytime the same password is entered in the system, else the system would be useless.

Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt this would be secure.  Unless you use a _huge_ password (like a paragraph of text), you won't have enough entropy to use the full keyspace.  I suppose it's unlikely that anyone who knows what they're doing would be interested in attacking your cryptosystem, but if someone did, I bet they could break it.

Comment: As long as the CSPRNG that is generating the random data based on password, has the avalance effect, and its cryptically strong, you would need to know the password to be able to generate the correct public/private keys. If the password is enough good, the only option would be to bruteforce the password. In this case, a SHA512 hash chain is used as random data, and the only way to get the correct hash would be to bruteforce the password.

Answer (score 0):

I would try Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA, it seems to bind
directly to libssl

Comment: Wont work. Tested it out: http://www.sebn.us.to/old/RSAgen.cgi

The full code: http://www.sebn.us.to/old/RSAgen.txt Even if I specify a random seed, OpenSSL seems to "add" random data to this seed. I would want the SAME public/private keypair to be generated each time the SAME password is entered.